# DNS failure on windows 7. browsers fail then crash, ping works

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I've been searching for solution to this since it started a couple of days ago and am at a loss. I brought my work HP notebook home and it connects to the router fine but all browsers fail on dns lookup (chrome,IE, Firefox, Opera). I can ping sites and the dns works, it seems just to be browsers, outlook and skype that fail. Skype and Chrome crash. When I try to connect to the notebook via Remote Desktop it crashes. I've had the notebook on my home network before without issues.

Error msgs

- Chrome: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET (then crash)
- IE: This page can't be displayed.
- Opera: Web page unavailable, cannot lookup google.com (then crash)
- Firefox: Just fails, no message
- Outlook: The server name you entered cannot be found...

Rebooting does not help. I've tried connecting to other networks and get the same result. I've checked the hosts file, flushed the dns and browser cashe, setting the dns server and double checked the winsock settings and turned off the firewall.

I've seen other posting with the same issue, but the above actions fixed it for them.

Comment: You'll need to take this up with your IT department.

Comment: We are a small company, I am the IT department. How is this off topic?

Comment: My apologies. We get a **lot** of people here asking questions about their work laptops and how to fix so-and-so, when they should be engaging their IT folks.

Comment: Did you perform a fresh Windows install? What group policies are applied to the machine? Is there any anti-virus/anti-malware/etc running on it? What is the firewall situation on the laptop?

Comment: How did you determine that the browsers are failing to perform DNS lookups? You say that you can ping websites and the DNS lookups succeed so how did you determine that DNS lookups in the browsers are failing? This doesn't sound like a DNS problem to me. Are your browsers configured to use a proxy server? Are you using Outlook Anywhere?

Comment: Smells suspiciously like malware to me.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a Windows user. But I know Windows has problems with ipv6 addresses. I figure, the DNS server might return ipv6 address first (it's considered preferable over ipv4) and your machine might not have ipv6 address, so it could not refer the site. But this is just a guess. Try to turn off ipv6 on your network device and check if the situation changes.

Comment: Turning off IPv6 is not the answer, especially on Windows. Microsoft has made it very clear that IPv6 must be left enabled if you want to remain in a supported configuration.

Comment: `I'm not a Windows user. But I know Windows has problems with ipv6 addresses` - So you don't use Windows yet you have some inside knowledge about IPv6 in Windows? Windows has problems with IPv6 addresses? Could you cite your sources and provide supporting links?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, fortunately. Had enough of that in the past, working as a system programmer for many years (so I know it from inside much better than the most users and programmers). But I'm a DNS server programmer and I know some about the problems and quirks Windows clients have with DNS. Windows had serious problems with ipv6. Windows 7, 8 srv 2008 and 2012 had troubles with ipv6 DHCP, they needed a patch. IE cannot normally work with direct ipv6 addresses (problem of literal UNC path names). So I guess this might be just another quirk of this sort. This would be not surprising.